# Why is my marching cubes algorythm leaving holes behind?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cubes

I just made a marching cubes algorythm and after 2 days i saw some holes in the mesh.

[image: Hole in marching cubes]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MarchinCubes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int size = 1;
    public float surfaceValue = .5f;

    public int xOffset = 0;
    public int yOffset = 0;
    public int zOffset = 0;

    public float zoom = 1;
    public bool interpolation;
    public bool shading;
    public bool autoUpdate;

    public bool sphereValues;

    void Start()
    {
        xOffset = (int)transform.position.x;
        yOffset = (int)transform.position.y;
        zOffset = (int)transform.position.z;

        Starter();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U) || autoUpdate)
        {
            xOffset = (int)transform.position.x;
            yOffset = (int)transform.position.y;
            zOffset = (int)transform.position.z;

            Starter();

            Vector3 position = transform.position;

            Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Floor(position.x), Mathf.Floor(position.y), Mathf.Floor(position.z));

            transform.position = newPosition;
        }
    }

    void Starter()
    {
        int pointSize = size + 1;
        float[][][] values = sphereValues ? sphere(pointSize) : Perlin(pointSize);

        Mesh mesh = CreateMesh(values, pointSize - 1);

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    }

    float[][][] sphere(int size)
    {
        float[][][] values = initializeFloatArray(size);

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    values[x][y][z] = 10 - distance(x, y, z, size / 2, size / 2, size / 2);
                }
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    float distance(float x, float y, float z, float xCenter, float yCenter, float zCenter)
    {
        return Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(x - xCenter, 2) + Mathf.Pow(y - yCenter, 2) + Mathf.Pow(z - zCenter, 2));
    }

    float[][][] Perlin(int size)
    {
        float[][][] values = initializeFloatArray(size);

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 || x == size - 1 || y == 0 || y == size - 1 ||z == 0 || z == size - 1)
                    {
                        values[x][y][z] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        values[x][y][z] = (GetPerlin(x, y, z, 40f) + GetPerlin(x, y, z, 20f)) / 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    float GetPerlin(int xInt, int yInt, int zInt, float divider)
    {
        float z = (zInt + zOffset) / divider;
        float y = (yInt + yOffset) / divider;
        float x = (xInt + xOffset) / divider;

        float zy = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, y);
        float zx = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, z);
        float yx = Mathf.PerlinNoise(y, z);
        float yz = Mathf.PerlinNoise(y, x);
        float xz = Mathf.PerlinNoise(z, x);
        float xy = Mathf.PerlinNoise(z, y);

        return (xy + xz + yz + yx + zx + zy) / 6;
    }

    float[][][] initializeFloatArray(int size)
    {
        float[][][] values = new float[size][][];

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            values[x] = new float[size][];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                values[x][i] = new float[size];
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    Mesh CreateMesh(float[][][] values, int size)
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = initializeVector3Array(size * 2 + 1, size * 2 + 1, size * 2 + 1);
        int[] triangles = new int[size * size * size * 3 * 2];
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        int triangleCount = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    int[] triangleTable = table[getTriangleIndex(
                        new[] {
                            values[x][y][z],
                            values[x + 1][y][z],
                            values[x + 1][y][z + 1],
                            values[x][y][z + 1],
                            values[x][y + 1][z],
                            values[x + 1][y + 1][z],
                            values[x + 1][y + 1][z + 1],
                            values[x][y + 1][z + 1]
                        },
                        surfaceValue)];

                    int[] trianglesToAdd = new int[triangleTable.Length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < triangleTable.Length; i += 3)
                    {
                        trianglesToAdd[i] = getVertexIndex(x, y, z, triangleTable[i], size * 2 + 2);
                        trianglesToAdd[i + 1] = getVertexIndex(x, y, z, triangleTable[i + 1], size * 2 + 2);
                        trianglesToAdd[i + 2] = getVertexIndex(x, y, z, triangleTable[i + 2], size * 2 + 2);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < trianglesToAdd.Length; i++)
                    {
                        triangles[triangleCount] = trianglesToAdd[i];
                        triangleCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (interpolation)
        {
            vertices = addIndterpolation(vertices, size * 2 + 2, values, surfaceValue);
        }

        vertices = ScaleVertices(vertices);

        if (shading == false)
        {
            RemakeMeshToDiscrete(vertices, triangles, out vertices, out triangles);
        }

        mesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        return mesh;
    }

    Vector3[] ScaleVertices(Vector3[] vertices)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].x = vertices[i].x / transform.localScale.x;
            vertices[i].y = vertices[i].y / transform.localScale.y;
            vertices[i].z = vertices[i].z / transform.localScale.z;
        }
        return vertices;
    }

    void RemakeMeshToDiscrete(Vector3[] vert, int[] trig, out Vector3[] outVertices, out int[] outTriangles)
    {
        Vector3[] vertDiscrete = new Vector3[trig.Length];
        int[] trigDiscrete = new int[trig.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < trig.Length; i++)
        {
            vertDiscrete[i] = vert[trig[i]];
            trigDiscrete[i] = i;
        }
        outVertices = vertDiscrete;
        outTriangles = trigDiscrete;
    }

    Vector3[] addIndterpolation(Vector3[] array, int sizeVertices, float[][][] values, float surfaceValue)
    {
        int sizeValues = values.Length;
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeValues - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < sizeValues - 1; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < sizeValues - 1; z++)
                {
                    int arrayCords = z * 2 + y * sizeVertices * 2 + x * sizeVertices * sizeVertices * 2;

                    float value = values[x][y][z];
                    float valueZ = values[x + 1][y][z];
                    float valueY = values[x][y + 1][z];
                    float valueX = values[x][y][z + 1];

                    float interpolationValueX = Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) / (Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) + Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - valueX));
                    float interpolationValueY = Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) / (Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) + Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - valueY));
                    float interpolationValueZ = Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) / (Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - value) + Mathf.Abs(surfaceValue - valueZ));

                    array[arrayCords + 1] += new Vector3(0, 0, interpolationValueX - .5f);

                    array[arrayCords + sizeVertices] += new Vector3(0, interpolationValueY - .5f, 0);

                    array[arrayCords + sizeVertices * sizeVertices] += new Vector3(interpolationValueZ - .5f, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    int getVertexIndex(int z, int y, int x, int cubeValue, int size)
    {
        int[][] vertecieValues = new[] {
            new []{1, 0, 0 },
            new []{2, 0, 1 },
            new []{1, 0, 2 },
            new []{0, 0, 1 },
            new []{1, 2, 0 },
            new []{2, 2, 1 },
            new []{1, 2, 2 },
            new []{0, 2, 1 },
            new []{0, 1, 0 },
            new []{2, 1, 0 },
            new []{2, 1, 2 },
            new []{0, 1, 2 }
        };

        int xReturn = z * 2 * size * size;
        int yReturn = y * 2 * size;
        int zReturn = x * 2;
        return xReturn + vertecieValues[cubeValue][0] * size * size + yReturn + vertecieValues[cubeValue][1] * size + zReturn + vertecieValues[cubeValue][2];
    }

    int getTriangleIndex(float[] values, float surfaceValue)
    {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] > surfaceValue)
            {
                index |= 1 << i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    Vector3[] initializeVector3Array(int Xsize, int Ysize, int Zsize)
    {
        Vector3[] array = new Vector3[(Xsize + 1) * (Ysize + 1) * (Zsize + 1)];
        int count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < Xsize + 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Ysize + 1; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < Zsize + 1; z++)
                {
                    array[count] = new Vector3(x / 2f, y / 2f, z / 2f);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    int[][] table = new int[][] {
        new int[] { },
        new int[] { 8, 3, 0},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 1},
        new int[] { 8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 9},
        new int[] {10, 1, 2},
        new int[] { 8, 3, 0, 1, 2,10},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 2, 9, 2,10},
        new int[] { 3, 2, 8, 2,10, 8, 8,10, 9},
        new int[] {11, 2, 3},
        new int[] {11, 2, 0,11, 0, 8},
        new int[] {11, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9},
        new int[] { 2, 1,11, 1, 9,11,11, 9, 8},
        new int[] {10, 1, 3,10, 3,11},
        new int[] { 1, 0,10, 0, 8,10,10, 8,11},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 9, 3,11, 9, 9,11,10},
        new int[] { 8,10, 9, 8,11,10},
        new int[] { 8, 4, 7},
        new int[] { 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 7},
        new int[] { 1, 9, 0, 8, 4, 7},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3},
        new int[] {10, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7},
        new int[] { 2,10, 1, 0, 4, 7, 0, 7, 3},
        new int[] { 4, 7, 8, 0, 2,10, 0,10, 9},
        new int[] { 2, 7, 3, 2, 9, 7, 7, 9, 4, 2,10, 9},
        new int[] { 2, 3,11, 7, 8, 4},
        new int[] { 7,11, 4,11, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0},
        new int[] { 3,11, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1},
        new int[] { 2, 7,11, 2, 1, 7, 1, 4, 7, 1, 9, 4},
        new int[] { 8, 4, 7,11,10, 1,11, 1, 3},
        new int[] {11, 4, 7, 1, 4,11, 1,11,10, 1, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 7,11, 4,11, 9, 4,11,10, 9},
        new int[] { 7,11, 4, 4,11, 9,11,10, 9},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 4},
        new int[] { 3, 0, 8, 4, 9, 5},
        new int[] { 5, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1},
        new int[] { 4, 8, 5, 8, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 2,10, 1, 9, 5, 4},
        new int[] { 0, 8, 3, 5, 4, 9,10, 1, 2},
        new int[] {10, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0},
        new int[] { 3, 4, 8, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 2,10, 5},
        new int[] {11, 2, 3, 9, 5, 4},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 4, 8,11, 2, 8, 2, 0},
        new int[] { 3,11, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4, 0},
        new int[] { 8, 5, 4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8,11, 2, 1, 5},
        new int[] { 5, 4, 9, 1, 3,11, 1,11,10},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 1, 4, 8, 5, 8,10, 5, 8,11,10},
        new int[] { 3, 4, 0, 3,10, 4, 4,10, 5, 3,11,10},
        new int[] { 4, 8, 5, 5, 8,10, 8,11,10},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 7, 9, 7, 8},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 3, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 7, 0, 1, 7, 7, 1, 5},
        new int[] { 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 1, 2,10, 5, 7, 8, 5, 8, 9},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 0,10, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3},
        new int[] { 5, 2,10, 8, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7, 8, 0, 2},
        new int[] {10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3},
        new int[] {11, 2, 3, 8, 9, 5, 8, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 9, 2, 0, 9, 7, 2, 2, 7,11, 9, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 8, 2, 1,11, 1, 7,11, 1, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 2, 1,11,11, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 3, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 7,11,10, 7,10, 5},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 0,10, 7,11,10, 5, 7},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 7,10, 5, 7,11,10},
        new int[] {11, 5, 7,11,10, 5},
        new int[] {10, 6, 5},
        new int[] { 8, 3, 0,10, 6, 5},
        new int[] { 0, 1, 9, 5,10, 6},
        new int[] {10, 6, 5, 9, 8, 3, 9, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 5},
        new int[] { 0, 8, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2, 5, 1},
        new int[] { 5, 9, 6, 9, 0, 6, 6, 0, 2},
        new int[] { 9, 6, 5, 3, 6, 9, 3, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 3,11, 2,10, 6, 5},
        new int[] { 6, 5,10, 2, 0, 8, 2, 8,11},
        new int[] { 1, 9, 0, 6, 5,10,11, 2, 3},
        new int[] { 1,10, 2, 5, 9, 6, 9,11, 6, 9, 8,11},
        new int[] {11, 6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1},
        new int[] { 0, 5, 1, 0,11, 5, 5,11, 6, 0, 8,11},
        new int[] { 0, 5, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3,11, 6},
        new int[] { 5, 9, 6, 6, 9,11, 9, 8,11},
        new int[] {10, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8},
        new int[] { 5,10, 6, 7, 3, 0, 7, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 5,10, 6, 0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 7},
        new int[] { 4, 5, 9, 6, 7,10, 7, 1,10, 7, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 7, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 4, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3, 2},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 5, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 4, 5, 9, 6, 3, 2, 6, 7, 3},
        new int[] { 7, 8, 4, 2, 3,11,10, 6, 5},
        new int[] {11, 6, 7,10, 2, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 4},
        new int[] {11, 6, 7, 8, 0, 3, 1,10, 2, 9, 4, 5},
        new int[] { 6, 7,11, 1,10, 2, 9, 4, 5},
        new int[] { 6, 7,11, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 6, 7,11, 4, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1},
        new int[] { 4, 5, 9, 3, 8, 0,11, 6, 7},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 5, 7,11, 6},
        new int[] {10, 6, 4,10, 4, 9},
        new int[] { 8, 3, 0, 9,10, 6, 9, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 1,10, 0,10, 6, 0, 0, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 8, 6, 4, 8, 1, 6, 6, 1,10, 8, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 8, 2, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 2, 4, 0, 2, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 3, 2, 8, 8, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 2, 3,11, 6, 4, 9, 6, 9,10},
        new int[] { 0,10, 2, 0, 9,10, 4, 8,11, 4,11, 6},
        new int[] {10, 2, 1,11, 6, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0},
        new int[] {10, 2, 1,11, 4, 8,11, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 1, 4, 9,11, 4, 1,11, 1, 3,11, 6, 4},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 1, 4,11, 6, 4, 8,11},
        new int[] {11, 6, 3, 3, 6, 0, 6, 4, 0},
        new int[] { 8, 6, 4, 8,11, 6},
        new int[] { 6, 7,10, 7, 8,10,10, 8, 9},
        new int[] { 9, 3, 0, 6, 3, 9, 6, 9,10, 6, 7, 3},
        new int[] { 6, 1,10, 6, 7, 1, 7, 0, 1, 7, 8, 0},
        new int[] { 6, 7,10,10, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 7, 2, 6, 7, 9, 2, 2, 9, 1, 7, 8, 9},
        new int[] { 1, 0, 9, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 7, 7, 0, 6, 0, 2, 6},
        new int[] { 2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7},
        new int[] { 7,11, 6, 3, 8, 2, 8,10, 2, 8, 9,10},
        new int[] {11, 6, 7,10, 0, 9,10, 2, 0},
        new int[] { 2, 1,10, 7,11, 6, 8, 0, 3},
        new int[] { 1,10, 2, 6, 7,11},
        new int[] { 7,11, 6, 3, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 0,11, 6, 7},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 8,11, 6, 7},
        new int[] {11, 6, 7},
        new int[] {11, 7, 6},
        new int[] { 0, 8, 3,11, 7, 6},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 1,11, 7, 6},
        new int[] { 7, 6,11, 3, 1, 9, 3, 9, 8},
        new int[] { 1, 2,10, 6,11, 7},
        new int[] { 2,10, 1, 7, 6,11, 8, 3, 0},
        new int[] {11, 7, 6,10, 9, 0,10, 0, 2},
        new int[] { 7, 6,11, 3, 2, 8, 8, 2,10, 8,10, 9},
        new int[] { 2, 3, 7, 2, 7, 6},
        new int[] { 8, 7, 0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 1, 9, 0, 3, 7, 6, 3, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 7, 6, 2, 7, 2, 9, 2, 1, 9, 7, 9, 8},
        new int[] { 6,10, 7,10, 1, 7, 7, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 6,10, 1, 6, 1, 7, 7, 1, 0, 7, 0, 8},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6,10, 9, 6, 3, 7},
        new int[] { 6,10, 7, 7,10, 8,10, 9, 8},
        new int[] { 8, 4, 6, 8, 6,11},
        new int[] {11, 3, 6, 3, 0, 6, 6, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 0, 1, 9, 4, 6,11, 4,11, 8},
        new int[] { 1, 9, 4,11, 1, 4,11, 3, 1,11, 4, 6},
        new int[] {10, 1, 2,11, 8, 4,11, 4, 6},
        new int[] {10, 1, 2,11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 0, 2,10, 0,10, 9, 4,11, 8, 4, 6,11},
        new int[] { 2,11, 3, 6, 9, 4, 6,10, 9},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 4, 6},
        new int[] { 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 6},
        new int[] { 1, 9, 0, 3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 8, 4, 6, 8, 6, 1, 6,10, 1, 8, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 1, 0,10,10, 0, 6, 0, 4, 6},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 3, 9, 6,10, 9, 4, 6},
        new int[] {10, 4, 6,10, 9, 4},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 4, 7, 6,11},
        new int[] { 4, 9, 5, 3, 0, 8,11, 7, 6},
        new int[] { 6,11, 7, 4, 0, 1, 4, 1, 5},
        new int[] { 6,11, 7, 4, 8, 5, 5, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 6,11, 7, 1, 2,10, 9, 5, 4},
        new int[] {11, 7, 6, 8, 3, 0, 1, 2,10, 9, 5, 4},
        new int[] {11, 7, 6,10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 0},
        new int[] { 7, 4, 8, 2,11, 3,10, 5, 6},
        new int[] { 4, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 3, 7},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 4, 8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 4, 0, 1, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6, 2, 3},
        new int[] { 7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 4, 9, 5, 6,10, 7, 7,10, 1, 7, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 5, 6,10, 0, 9, 1, 8, 7, 4},
        new int[] { 5, 6,10, 7, 0, 3, 7, 4, 0},
        new int[] {10, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7},
        new int[] { 5, 6, 9, 6,11, 9, 9,11, 8},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 5, 0, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 6,11},
        new int[] { 0, 1, 5, 0, 5,11, 5, 6,11, 0,11, 8},
        new int[] {11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5},
        new int[] { 1, 2,10, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6,11, 9,11, 8},
        new int[] { 1, 0, 9, 6,10, 5,11, 3, 2},
        new int[] { 6,10, 5, 2, 8, 0, 2,11, 8},
        new int[] { 3, 2,11,10, 5, 6},
        new int[] { 9, 5, 6, 3, 9, 6, 3, 8, 9, 3, 6, 2},
        new int[] { 5, 6, 9, 9, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 8, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5},
        new int[] { 1, 6, 2, 1, 5, 6},
        new int[] {10, 5, 6, 9, 3, 8, 9, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 1, 5, 6,10},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 3,10, 5, 6},
        new int[] {10, 5, 6},
        new int[] {11, 7, 5,11, 5,10},
        new int[] { 3, 0, 8, 7, 5,10, 7,10,11},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 1,10,11, 7,10, 7, 5},
        new int[] { 3, 1, 9, 3, 9, 8, 7,10,11, 7, 5,10},
        new int[] { 2,11, 1,11, 7, 1, 1, 7, 5},
        new int[] { 0, 8, 3, 2,11, 1, 1,11, 7, 1, 7, 5},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 2, 9, 2, 7, 2,11, 7, 9, 7, 5},
        new int[] {11, 3, 2, 8, 5, 9, 8, 7, 5},
        new int[] {10, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7},
        new int[] { 5,10, 2, 8, 5, 2, 8, 7, 5, 8, 2, 0},
        new int[] { 9, 0, 1,10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7},
        new int[] { 1,10, 2, 5, 8, 7, 5, 9, 8},
        new int[] { 1, 3, 7, 1, 7, 5},
        new int[] { 8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5},
        new int[] { 9, 7, 5, 9, 8, 7},
        new int[] { 4, 5, 8, 5,10, 8, 8,10,11},
        new int[] { 3, 0, 4, 3, 4,10, 4, 5,10, 3,10,11},
        new int[] { 0, 1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 8, 5,10, 8,10,11},
        new int[] { 5, 9, 4, 1,11, 3, 1,10,11},
        new int[] { 8, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 2,11, 8, 2, 5, 1},
        new int[] { 3, 2,11, 1, 4, 5, 1, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 5, 8, 2,11, 8, 0, 2},
        new int[] {11, 3, 2, 9, 4, 5},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5,10},
        new int[] {10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 0, 4},
        new int[] { 0, 3, 8, 5, 9, 4,10, 2, 1},
        new int[] { 2, 1,10, 9, 4, 5},
        new int[] { 4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3},
        new int[] { 5, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 4, 5, 9},
        new int[] { 9, 4, 5},
        new int[] { 7, 4,11, 4, 9,11,11, 9,10},
        new int[] { 3, 0, 8, 7, 4,11,11, 4, 9,11, 9,10},
        new int[] {11, 7, 4, 1,11, 4, 1,10,11, 1, 4, 0},
        new int[] { 8, 7, 4,11, 1,10,11, 3, 1},
        new int[] { 2,11, 7, 2, 7, 1, 1, 7, 4, 1, 4, 9},
        new int[] { 3, 2,11, 4, 8, 7, 9, 1, 0},
        new int[] { 7, 4,11,11, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2},
        new int[] { 2,11, 3, 7, 4, 8},
        new int[] { 2, 3, 7, 2, 7, 9, 7, 4, 9, 2, 9,10},
        new int[] { 4, 8, 7, 0,10, 2, 0, 9,10},
        new int[] { 2, 1,10, 0, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7},
        new int[] {10, 2, 1, 8, 7, 4},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 4, 4, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7},
        new int[] { 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 4},
        new int[] { 3, 4, 0, 3, 7, 4},
        new int[] { 8, 7, 4},
        new int[] { 8, 9,10, 8,10,11},
        new int[] { 0, 9, 3, 3, 9,11, 9,10,11},
        new int[] { 1,10, 0, 0,10, 8,10,11, 8},
        new int[] {10, 3, 1,10,11, 3},
        new int[] { 2,11, 1, 1,11, 9,11, 8, 9},
        new int[] {11, 3, 2, 0, 9, 1},
        new int[] {11, 0, 2,11, 8, 0},
        new int[] {11, 3, 2},
        new int[] { 3, 8, 2, 2, 8,10, 8, 9,10},
        new int[] { 9, 2, 0, 9,10, 2},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 3, 1,10, 2},
        new int[] {10, 2, 1},
        new int[] { 8, 1, 3, 8, 9, 1},
        new int[] { 9, 1, 0},
        new int[] { 8, 0, 3},
        new int[] {}
    };
}
```

I know the code is really messy but the problem probably is in the CreateMesh method or in the triangulation table.

Does someone know why the hole is appearing there?
I have the triangulation table from the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that those faces aren't just back-facing? (I can't test your code at the moment, but it's easy to check if you just look at the model from the other side.)

Comment: Nope they are completly missing.

Comment: I looked over this for a while and couldn't find an immediately apparent answer. I did notice that getVertexIndex flips the order of x,y,z but compensates by multiplying size the correct amount of times in the flipped places. Do you think your error could be here?

Comment: Also tip: the 6 noise planes approach isn't necessarily the best quality (or fastest) way to generate 3D noise. Unity's Mathf.PerlinNoise also produces very grid-aligned results on its own. Substituting in a simplex-type noise from an external .cs file should solve both of those issues. I'll link the one from my repo because it has an "open implementation" for 3D, which not all have, but it's certainly not the only option out there. Note: To rescale this [-1,1] noise to [0,1] you'll need to do noise() * 0.5 + 0.5 when substituting it. https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/tree/master/csharp

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will try to use your simplex noise and look if i have any missing sqares again.

Comment: Ok i tested it out and i still had issues with missing squares. Here are some images: https://imgur.com/a/swkrDTh and heres the new code: https://pastebin.com/eKCBayij

Comment: Right - I didn't expect it to solve the squares! Just a better solution for noise IMO, so that once you also resolve the squares, your terrain has nicer shapes too. And looks like you got it resolved!

Comment: Also if Z is your vertical direction, I like to use Noise3_XYBeforeZ, or if Y is your vertical direction I like to use Noise3_XZBeforeY. A further slight improvement in feature distribution, but not as huge as the jump from perlin to simplex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed with a new triangulation table. Thanks for your help.